# How can i search and replace using python regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to make the function which find for string in the array and then replace the corres[ponding element from the dictionary. so far i have tried this but i am not able to figure out few things like

1. How can escape special characters
2. I can i replace with match found. i tried `\1` but it didn't work

dsds

```
def myfunc(h):
        myarray = {
                "#":"\\#",
                "$":"\\$",
                "%":"\\%",
                "&":"\\&",
                "~":"\\~{}",
                "_":"\\_",
                "^":"\\^{}",
                "\\":"\\textbackslash{}",
                "{":"\\{",
                "}":"\\}"                
                    }
        pattern = "[#\$\%\&\~\_\^\\\\\{\}]"
        pattern_obj = re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE)
        new = re.sub(pattern_obj,myarray[\1],h)

        return new
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for re.sub callbacks:

```
def myfunc(h):
    rules = {
            "#":r"\#",
            "$":r"\$",
            "%":r"\%",
            "&":r"\&",
            "~":r"\~{}",
            "_":r"\_",
            "^":r"\^{}",
            "\\":r"\textbackslash{}",
            "{":r"\{",
            "}":r"\}"                
    }
    pattern = '[%s]' % re.escape(''.join(rules.keys()))
    new = re.sub(pattern, lambda m: rules[m.group()], h)
    return new
```

This way you avoid 1) loops, 2) replacing already processed content.

Comment: i am not able to figure out what will be input parameter to lambda , and how will that gets passed

Comment: @user196264097: the parameter is a Match object (http://docs.python.org/dev/library/re.html#re.sub)

Comment: thanks man , i wonder you guys read  every line of the documentation. i have usually gone through the docs but not line by line. I am usually stuck where i skip the lines :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use re.sub inside a loop that iterates over myarray.items(). However, you'll have to do backslash first since otherwise that might replace things incorrectly. You also need to make sure that "{" and "}" happen first, so that you don't mix up the matching. Since dictionaries are unordered I suggest you use list of tuples instead:

```
def myfunc(h):
    myarray = [
            ("\\","\\textbackslash")
            ("{","\\{"),
            ("}","\\}"),
            ("#","\\#"),
            ("$","\\$"),
            ("%","\\%"),
            ("&","\\&"),
            ("~","\\~{}"),
            ("_","\\_"),
            ("^","\\^{}")]

    for (val, replacement) in myarray:
        h = re.sub(val, replacement, h)
    h = re.sub("\\textbackslash", "\\textbackslash{}", h)

    return h
```

Comment: I feel that `h.replace(val, replacement)` could be faster than `re.sub(val, replacement, h)` and will fit our question's case.

Comment: yes, I am not too familiar with the performance differences, but I think yours is more readable.

Comment: Thanks. Just was curious: yes, `str.replace` is faster than `re.sub`. 6.7x faster according to tests on my PC :)

Answer (score 1):

1. I'd suggest you to use raw literal syntax (`r""`) for better readability of the code.
2. For the case of your array you may want just to use [`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) function instead of `re.sub`.

```py
def myfunc(h):
    myarray = [
            ("\\", r"\textbackslash"),
            ("{", r"\{"),
            ("}", r"\}"),
            ("#", r"\#"),
            ("$", r"\$"),
            ("%", r"\%"),
            ("&", r"\&"),
            ("~", r"\~{}"),
            ("_", r"\_"),
            ("^", r"\^{}")]

    for (val, replacement) in myarray:
        h = h.replace(val, replacement)
    h = h.replace(r"\textbackslash", r"\textbackslash{}", h)

    return h
```

The code is a modification of @tigger's answer.

Answer (score 0):

to escape metacharacters, use raw string and backslashes

```
r"regexp with a \* in it"
```